# How should this question be improved? It was downvoted

Tags: support, specific-question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336043/sed-executes-normally-except-when-reading-script-bad-flag-in-substitute-command) was a puzzling one: instructing `sed` to read a script file, upon which it signals a Bad Flag. It turned out that the script file was in little endian Unicode 16, a format that all editors I used (including Vim) read without issues, but that `sed` cannot interpret; it requires ASCII. User *jerry* helpfully offered a method to determine file format, which solved the issue.

The question was downvoted. When I linger on the downvote link, it states: "This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear or not useful". This leaves me wondering: How do I improve it?

Comment: I was halfway through writing a long winded answer _here_, when I found a very useful duplicate for your question _there_. I have suggested the duplicate. Basically what your question boils down to is using Windows new line characters as input on a *nix based system.

Comment: Yes that was indeed the issue - the first layer of it. This was offered as an answer by myself, then @jerry identified the lingering remainder: once all Windows CRs were substituted for Unix ones, there still was an underlying issue that could not be fixed by the solutions in your suggested duplicate. No amount of troubleshooting on my mac could find the cause of why `sed` still threw an error. `dos2unix` only changed the CRs, not the file format.

Comment: I think it is downvoted because of the "This question does not show any **research effort**" part: it is an exact duplicate of an existing one. Furthermore, you only have one downvote, I don't think it deserves a Meta post...